# ServiceConnect["Facebook"] error

Tags: functions, social-media

ServiceConnect["Facebook","New"] return error:
ServiceConnect: Due to restrictions added by Facebook, this service is currently not available.

But when I check Wolfram Mathematica's 13.0 documentation, there's no mention about function's inaccessibility. Just want to know if it's my setup that is wrong or if Facebook connection is no longer supported.

Comment: This and similar services (eg Twitter) have long been non-functioning.

Comment: Thank you very much!